# Get Google Calendar events using Perl without any modules? Just API

Tags: api, google-calendar-api

I've now spent about 3 hours trying to figure out how to use the Google Calendar API and I'm still in square one. I don't want to install any extra modules. I just want to do this with GET commands. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an API key and the calendarId, it [seems to be very simple](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#retrieving_events).